# Fuzzy matching with regex in Python - Why so slow?

Tags: python, regex, matching

I'm trying to fuzzymatch columns from two different .csv files. Here is the script:

```
import regex
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('messy.csv', header = None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('correct.csv', header = None)

df1_1 = df1[3]
df2_2 = df2[0]

for x in df1_1:
    r = r"(?:%s){2i+2d+1s<=%s}" %(x, int(len(x)*.2))
    f = lambda y : bool(regex.match(r, y, regex.IGNORECASE))
    mask = df2_2.apply(f)
    results = [x, df2_2[mask].values]
    print(results)
```

After having matched the two columns Python returns a few suggestions according to the error I defined i.e {2i+2d+1s<=%s}. In some cases there are too many suggestions. Is there a way of limiting them (apart from tweaking the error term)?

Regex doesn't seem to be very accurate sometimes. Are there similar ways of fuzzymatching two strings? I have already tried fuzzywuzzy. It's amazing but it's terribly slow (it's the reason I switched to regex in the first place).

Thanks! Feel free to comment on the code as well!

Comment: -1 because this is asking for too many different things at once (an explanation of why this is slow, a way of limiting the number of matches returned, recommendations of competing libraries, a review of the code posted, and, possibly, an explanation of why regex isn't always "accurate", though I'm unsure what you mean by that). On top of that, there's no example data that you run this code on so we have no chance to reproduce the slowness you mention in order to try to understand or fix it, which makes the primary question here pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: It seems like there might be a fine question hidden under the surface here, but until the problems I mention above are all chipped away to reveal that question, I'm voting to close.